# Is it possible to decrypt a file into memory and use it via the command line in Python?

Tags: python, file, memory

I was wondering if it is possible to take a pre-encrypted file (i.e., AES encrypted file), then decrypt it into memory space only and then use it while still in memory as a file to be executed on a command line?

The overall goal is to use a program called Yara to scan for malicious files.  However, I am going to be running it in an environment where I want the ruleset to be encrypted/encoded so the user's workstation I am running it on can't acquire the ruleset in the clear.  The command line goes something like the following:

yara.exe (ruleset file) (directory or file to scan)

Right now I have it setup where I decrypt a pre-encrypted AES file that is also encoded in Base64 and then write it out to a file temporarily and used for the scan and after the scan is completed it is deleted.

This works because it has a physical ruleset file to work with, but to make it even more secure would be to have it so the decrypted ruleset only exist in memory and then utilized via the command line above.  Probably answering my own question, but I suppose its not possible since the file exist in memory and the program wants a physical file to be used.  The only way I could pull this off is if I edited the program to itself to include this encrypted file as a resource or something and decode it in memory space and use it by default.  I suppose I will just have to live with what I am currently doing.  Anyone else have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [Yara from Python](http://yara.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/yarapython.html), it seems possible.  Decode the rule file into memory using pycrypto or equivalent, then use

```
rules = yara.compile(source=my_decoded_rules)
```